# Having trouble with Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The following code doesn't yield any results from Mathematica:

```
Maximize[
  {Beta[1 + 2 n (p - 1)/p, 1 + 2 m (p - 1)/p] Beta[1 + 2 n/p, 1 + 
     2 m/p]/Beta[n + 1, m + 1]^2, 
   n >= 0 && m >= 0 && p == 4}, 
  {n, m}]
```

Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: I wonder why you put a constraint like `p==4`.

Comment: If you try `NMaximixe` it will give a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NMaximize[{Beta[1 + 2 n (p - 1)/p,1 + 2 m (p - 1)/p] Beta[1 + 2 n/p, 1 + 2 m/p]/Beta[n + 1, m + 1]^2 /. p -> 4, n >= 0 && m >= 0 }, {n, m}]
(*{1.1547, {n -> 2.83145*10^6, m -> 4.82625*10^6}}*)
```

Comment: Did you plot the function under consideration?

Comment: No, OP only asked for a global maximum.